# How to display article with rich media: text, image, youtube, soundcloud etc

Tags: android, xamarin, youtube, xamarin.android, media

Im making an app that will have articles, an article can have **text, image, youtube, soundcloud** etc.

I want to be able to do that easy and without a lot of code like having to copy and paste the url.

Im thinking this approach:

- Having the app to use a Parse.com Server
- set the App database to something like this: article id, title,
  category, text,  image-1, image-2, youtube-1, youtube-2, soundcloud-1 etc

and display the article in this way:

- upload the image youtube url etx to the server and then in the text field use placeholder to display my rich media.

For example this text:

*[image-1]Hello world [youtube-1]*

Will be converted on the fly to a relative layout that will have first an **Imageview**, below the imageview a **Textview**, below the textview, a youtube video.

Is this the best way to do what i want? is another better way to do something like this?

Comment: Considered using a.... WebView?

Comment: this requires to have a web server and to build first the webpage and then to add it to the app, there isn't a better solution? my idea is bad? i should definetely use webview?

Comment: also i dont want this content to be accesible from outside the app

Answer (score 0):

WebView and Wordpress is the way to go after a research.

Now that Wordpress has REST API you have a superb writer and a blog for your sites and you can fetch them. I really think is the best and simpler solution.